# MVC 3 ModelView passing parameters between view & controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0

I've been playing with MVC 3 in a test project and have the following issue.

I have Group & Subscriber entities and those are coupled through a SubscriberGroup table.

Using the DetailView of Group I open a view of SubscriberGroup containing all subscribers. 
This list has the option to filter.

So far it all works, however when I call the AddToGroup method on the controller it fails. Specifically it goes into the method but doesn't pass the subscriberCheckedModels list. 
Am I doing something wrong?

View:    SubscriberGroup             Index.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Mail.Models.SubscriberCheckedListViewModel>" %>
…
<h2 class="common-box-title">
        Add Subscribers to Group</h2>
    <p>
        <% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "SubscriberGroup"))
           { %>
            <input name="filter" id="filter" type="text" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />

        <%} %>
    </p>
            <% using (Html.BeginForm("AddToGroup", "SubscriberGroup", Model,FormMethod.Get, null))
           { %>
           <fieldset>
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 70%; vertical-align: top;">
        <% if (Model.subscribers.Count() != 0)
           { %>
        <table class="hor-minimalist-b">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Add To Group
                </th>
                <th>
                    Full Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Email
                </th>
                <th>
                    Customer
                </th>
            </tr>
            <% foreach (var item in Model.subscribers)
               { %>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.AddToGroup)%>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>  item.subscriber.LastName)%>
                    <%= Html.ActionLink(item.subscriber.FirstName + " " + item.subscriber.LastName, "Details", new { id = item.subscriber.SubscriberID })%>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.subscriber.Email)%>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.subscriber.Customer.Company)%>
                    <%= Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.subscriber) %>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <% } %>
            <% ViewBag.subscribers = Model.subscribers; %>                                    probeersel
            <%= Html.HiddenFor(model => model.subscribers) %>                                 probeersel
        </table>
        <%} %>
        <%else
           { %>
        <p>
            No subscribers found.</p>
        <%} %>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Subscribers" />
    </div>
    </fieldset>
            <%} %>
```

Controller:          SubscriberGroupController

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
using Mail.Models;

namespace Mail.Controllers
{
    public class SubscriberGroupController : Controller
    {
        private int groupID;
        private MailDBEntities db = new MailDBEntities();
        //
        // GET: /SubscriberGroup/

        public ActionResult Index(int id)
        {
            groupID = id;
            MembershipUser myObject = Membership.GetUser();
            Guid UserID = Guid.Parse(myObject.ProviderUserKey.ToString());
            UserCustomer usercustomer = db.UserCustomers.Single(s => s.UserID == UserID);
            var subscribers = from subscriber in db.Subscribers
                              where (subscriber.CustomerID == usercustomer.CustomerID) | (subscriber.CustomerID == 0)
                              select new SubscriberCheckedModel { subscriber = subscriber, AddToGroup = false };
            SubscriberCheckedListViewModel test = new SubscriberCheckedListViewModel();
            test.subscribers = subscribers;
            return View(test);
        }



        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string filter)
        {
            MembershipUser myObject = Membership.GetUser();
            Guid UserID = Guid.Parse(myObject.ProviderUserKey.ToString());
            UserCustomer usercustomer = db.UserCustomers.Single(s => s.UserID == UserID);
            var subscribers2 = from subscriber in db.Subscribers
                               where ((subscriber.FirstName.Contains(filter)|| subscriber.LastName.Contains(filter))
                               && (subscriber.CustomerID == usercustomer.CustomerID || subscriber.CustomerID == 0))
                               select new SubscriberCheckedModel { subscriber = subscriber, AddToGroup = false };
            SubscriberCheckedListViewModel test = new SubscriberCheckedListViewModel();
            test.subscribers = subscribers2.ToList();
            return View(test);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddToGroup(SubscriberCheckedListViewModel test)
        {
            //test is null 
            return RedirectToAction("Details", "Group", new { id = groupID });
        }


    }
}
```

ViewModel:      SubscriberGroupModel

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Mail;
namespace Mail.Models
{
    public class SubscriberCheckedModel
    {
        public Subscriber subscriber { get; set; }
        public bool AddToGroup { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubscriberCheckedListViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<SubscriberCheckedModel> subscribers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: does the AddToGroupMethod see the values in the model.

Comment: One possible inconsistency that I can see, `Html.BeginForm("AddToGroup", "SubscriberGroup", Model,FormMethod.Get, null)` is doing a `GET`, but your action is marked with `[HttpPost]`. I don't know if it'll make a difference for you though.

Comment: M.Babcock, this was part of one of the attempts to fix the situation, so httppost was the original value. But thanks!

Comment: Brian, the AddToGroup receives an object of type SubscriberCheckedListViewModel and it contains an empty list of subscribers, even though it showed 2 subscribers on the index page.

Answer (score 1):

IEnumerable will not binded automatically, we need to modify the foreach loop in the view with follows,

```
<% for (int i=0;i<Model.subscribers.Count();i++) 
               { %> 
            <tr> 
                <td> 
                    <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.subscribers[i].AddToGroup)%> 
                </td> 
                <td> 
                    <%= Html.DisplayFor(Model =>  Model.subscribers[i].subscriber.LastName)%> 
                    <%= Html.ActionLink(Model.subscribers[i].subscriber.FirstName + " " + Model.subscribers[i].subscriber.LastName, "Details", new { id = Model.subscribers[i].subscriber.SubscriberID })%> 
                </td> 
                <td> 
                    <%: Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.subscribers[i].subscriber.Email)%> 
                </td> 
                <td> 
                    <%: Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.subscribers[i].subscriber.Customer.Company)%> 
                    <%= Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.subscribers[i].subscriber) %> 
                </td> 
            </tr> 
            <% } %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer!
When I apply your changes '<% for (int i = 0; i < Model.subscribers.Count(); i++)
               { %>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.subscribers[i].AddToGroup)%>
                </td>' 
It says 
"Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type '..IEnumerable<..SubscriberCheckedModel>" on Model.subscribers[i]...
and "A local variable named Model cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to Model, which is already used in a parent ..." on Model

Comment: What do you want to know? I think the comment part is incomplete

Comment: Should I change the IEnumerable in the viewmodel to a list perhaps?

Comment: OK, Instead of using Model=>Model. use something like m=>m.  as Model has a different meaning.

Comment: In a View Model refers to Current ViewModel view is attached to, but in a lmbda expression it needs a different name

Comment: Done, and it renders perfectly. (Had to change the collection type in the viewmodel from IEnumerable to List<> though. However the AddToGroup method still receives an empty SubscriberCheckedListViewModel object (not null, just empty). 
Also I noticed the GroupID being set in the index method doesn't remain in memory. GroupID is 0 when it gets to AddToGroup. Even placing it in the ViewBag doesn't work. Don't know if it's relevant.

Comment: ViewBag will not help. We can have it as a hidden field in view, and then read it back in "AddToGroup" from Request valueprovider.

Comment: this.ValueProvider.GetValue("GroupId") //GroupId is the key used in hidden field

Comment: But Ideal way will be to have a property in SubscriberCheckedListViewModel and populate the value in Index(..) and read it back in AddToGroup,

Comment: Ok, but the problem remains, the object which is being received by AddToGroup method is still empty. So even if I add the GroupID variable, it will still be empty.

Comment: You need to have it in the view as hidden field

Comment: I already had, like you suggested, placed             
<%= Html.HiddenFor(model => model.subscribers) %> 
in the index page.

Comment: So the parameter I pass to the index page is not retained when entering the AddToGroup method, even though I have the hiddenfor implemented.

Comment: It should work fine, any way i will try to give in detail in my next post

Answer (score 0):

First Lets modify your model to have Id field

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Mail;
namespace Mail.Models
{
    public class SubscriberCheckedModel
    {
        public Subscriber subscriber { get; set; }
        public bool AddToGroup { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubscriberCheckedListViewModel
    {
        int GroupId{get;set;}
        public IEnumerable<SubscriberCheckedModel> subscribers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now lets modify controller,

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.Web.Security;
    using Mail.Models;

    namespace Mail.Controllers
    {
        public class SubscriberGroupController : Controller
        {
            private int groupID;
            private MailDBEntities db = new MailDBEntities();
            //
            // GET: /SubscriberGroup/

            public ActionResult Index(int id)
            {
                groupID = id;
                MembershipUser myObject = Membership.GetUser();
                Guid UserID = Guid.Parse(myObject.ProviderUserKey.ToString());
                UserCustomer usercustomer = db.UserCustomers.Single(s => s.UserID == UserID);
                var subscribers = from subscriber in db.Subscribers
                                  where (subscriber.CustomerID == usercustomer.CustomerID) | (subscriber.CustomerID == 0)
                                  select new SubscriberCheckedModel { subscriber = subscriber, AddToGroup = false };
                SubscriberCheckedListViewModel test = new SubscriberCheckedListViewModel();
                test.subscribers = subscribers;
test.GroupId=groupID;
                return View(test);
            }



            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Index(string filter)
            {
                MembershipUser myObject = Membership.GetUser();
                Guid UserID = Guid.Parse(myObject.ProviderUserKey.ToString());
                UserCustomer usercustomer = db.UserCustomers.Single(s => s.UserID == UserID);
                var subscribers2 = from subscriber in db.Subscribers
                                   where ((subscriber.FirstName.Contains(filter)|| subscriber.LastName.Contains(filter))
                                   && (subscriber.CustomerID == usercustomer.CustomerID || subscriber.CustomerID == 0))
                                   select new SubscriberCheckedModel { subscriber = subscriber, AddToGroup = false };
                SubscriberCheckedListViewModel test = new SubscriberCheckedListViewModel();
                test.subscribers = subscribers2.ToList();
                return View(test);
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult AddToGroup(SubscriberCheckedListViewModel test)
            {
                var id=test.GroupId; 
                return RedirectToAction("Details", "Group", new { id = groupID });
            }


        }
```

Now lets modify the view,

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Mail.Models.SubscriberCheckedListViewModel>" %>
…
<h2 class="common-box-title">
        Add Subscribers to Group</h2>
    <p>
        <% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "SubscriberGroup"))
           { %>
            <input name="filter" id="filter" type="text" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />

        <%} %>
    </p>
            <% using (Html.BeginForm("AddToGroup", "SubscriberGroup", Model,FormMethod.Get, null))
           { %>
           <fieldset>
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 70%; vertical-align: top;">
        <% if (Model.subscribers.Count() != 0)
           { %>
           <%: Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.GroupId) %>
        <table class="hor-minimalist-b">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Add To Group
                </th>
                <th>
                    Full Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Email
                </th>
                <th>
                    Customer
                </th>
            </tr>
            <% for (int i=0;i<Model.subscribers.Count();i++) 
               { %> 
            <tr> 
                <td> 
                    <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(M => M.subscribers[i].AddToGroup)%> 
                </td> 
                <td> 
                    <%= Html.DisplayFor(M =>  M.subscribers[i].subscriber.LastName)%> 
                    <%= Html.ActionLink(Model.subscribers[i].subscriber.FirstName + " " + Model.subscribers[i].subscriber.LastName, "Details", new { id = Model.subscribers[i].subscriber.SubscriberID })%> 
                </td> 
                <td> 
                    <%: Html.DisplayFor(M => M.subscribers[i].subscriber.Email)%> 
                </td> 
                <td> 
                    <%: Html.DisplayFor(M => M.subscribers[i].subscriber.Customer.Company)%> 
                    <%= Html.HiddenFor(M => M.subscribers[i].subscriber) %> 
                </td> 
            </tr> 
            <% } %>
            <% ViewBag.subscribers = Model.subscribers; %>                                    probeersel
            <%= Html.HiddenFor(model => model.subscribers) %>                                 probeersel
        </table>
        <%} %>
        <%else
           { %>
        <p>
            No subscribers found.</p>
        <%} %>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Subscribers" />
    </div>
    </fieldset>
            <%} %>
```

Give it a TRY....

Comment: Hey Manas!

First of all, thanks so much for spending so much time on this issue!
Now I wish I could say it works, but still an error.

When submitting the view, it links to following url which displays "The resource cannot be found.".

http://localhost:61838/SubscriberGroup/AddToGroup?GroupID=1&subscribers%5B0%5D.AddToGroup=true&subscribers%5B0%5D.AddToGroup=false&subscribers%5B0%5D.subscriber=Mail.Subscriber&subscribers%5B1%5D.AddToGroup=false&subscribers%5B1%5D.subscriber=Mail.Subscriber&subscribers=System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BMail.Models.SubscriberCheckedModel%5D

Comment: http://localhost:61838/SubscriberGroup/

AddToGroup?
GroupID=1
&subscribers%5B0%5D.AddToGroup=true
&subscribers%5B0%5D.AddToGroup=false
&subscribers%5B0%5D.subscriber=Mail.Subscriber
&subscribers%5B1%5D.AddToGroup=false
&subscribers%5B1%5D.subscriber=Mail.Subscriber
&subscribers=System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BMail.Models.SubscriberCheckedModel%5D

Comment: To make certain I set a breakpoint in the AddToGroup method but it didn't trigger.